# Pyreverse fails to generate any output files (png, jpg) other than .dot files

Tags: python-3.x, pylint, pyreverse

I am attempting to use pylint's pyreverse to generate uml diagrams of some .

When I run pyreverse from the command shell

```
pyreverse <modulename>
```

It executes just fine and returns a *.dot file as it should. If I attempt to use output options such as "-o png" I get the following error

```
>pyreverse -o png <modulename>
'c:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I am running python 3.6.5 and pylint 2.1.1.
I have installed graphviz 2.38 under C:\Programs and added the bin directory to my windows path.

I suspect pyreverse is recognizing some command as a command and a set of arguments (e.g. "C:\Program Files\blah blah" is being sent as a command to the windows interpreter as "C:\Program", but I do not know where, or how to fix it.

Can anyone offer any solutions?

Comment: Do you mind creating an issue at github.com/PyCQA/pylint? Might be a bug in pyreverse.

Answer (score 0):

That is a bug as the commenter suggested.

In the meanwhile, install graphviz, so that `dot` is on the path, then run

`dot -Tpng classes.dot>result.png`